# Calculate partitioned sum efficiently with CuPy or NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cupy

I have a very long array* of length `L` (let's call it `values`) that I want to sum over, and a sorted 1D array of the same length `L` that contains `N` integers with which to partition the original array – let's call this array `labels`.

What I'm currently doing is this (`module` being `cupy` or `numpy`):

```
result = module.empty(N)
for i in range(N):
    result[i] = values[labels == i].sum()
```

But this can't be the most efficient way of doing it (it should be possible to get rid of the `for` loop, but how?). Since `labels` is sorted, I could easily determine the break points and use those indices as start/stop points, but I don't see how this solves the `for` loop problem.

Note that I would like to avoid creating an array of size `N`x`L` along the way, if possible, since `L` is very large.

I'm working in cupy, but any numpy solution is welcome too and could probably be ported. Within cupy, it seems this would be a case for a `ReductionKernel`, but I don't quite see how to do it.

---

* in my case, `values` is 1D, but I assume the solution wouldn't depend on this

Answer (score 2):

You are describing a groupby sum aggregation. You could write a CuPy `RawKernel` for this, but it would be **much** easier to use the existing groupby aggregations implemented in [cuDF](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf), the GPU dataframe library. They can interoperate without requiring you to copy the data. If you call `.values` on the resulting cuDF Series, it will give you a CuPy array.

If you went back to the CPU, you could do the same thing with pandas.

```py
import cupy as cp
import pandas as pd

N = 100
values = cp.random.randint(0, N, 1000)
labels = cp.sort(cp.random.randint(0, N, 1000))

L = len(values)
result = cp.empty(L)
for i in range(N):
    result[i] = values[labels == i].sum()
    
result[:5]
array([547., 454., 402., 601., 668.])
```

```py
import cudf

df = cudf.DataFrame({"values": values, "labels": labels})
df.groupby(["labels"])["values"].sum().values[:5]
array([547, 454, 402, 601, 668])
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely look into cuDF and profile/time the different versions against each other, that might be a good solution. But I think you forgot to use pandas in the first snippet you posted? Seems to be the same thing (i.e. using `for`) that I'm currently doing.

Comment: Oops, I get what you're trying to show there, sorry, forget what I said about pandas.

Comment: Also, sorry for the spam, but I just realized that my `results` array should have had length `N`, not `L`. I assume you were probably also tacitly irritated by that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which, instead of a `N x L` array, uses a `N x <max partition size in labels>` array (which should not be large, if the disparity between different partitions is not too high):

1. Resize the array into a 2-D array with partitions in each row. Since the length of the row equals the size of the maximum partition, fill unavailable values with zeros (since it doesn't affect any sum). This uses @Divakar's solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62838445/12983399).

```
def jagged_to_regular(a, parts):
    lens = np.ediff1d(parts,to_begin=parts[0])
    mask = lens[:,None]>np.arange(lens.max())
    out = np.zeros(mask.shape, dtype=a.dtype)
    out[mask] = a
    return out

parts_stack = jagged_to_regular(values, labels)
```

2. Sum along axis 1:

```
result = np.sum(parts_stack, axis = 1)
```

In case you'd like a CuPy implementation, there's no direct CuPy [alternative](https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/comparison.html#numpy-cupy-apis) to `numpy.ediff1d` in `jagged_to_regular`. In that case, you can substitute the statement with `numpy.diff` like so:

```
lens = np.insert(np.diff(parts), 0, parts[0])
```

and then continue to use CuPy as a drop-in replacement for numpy.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I'll also test this against Nick Becker's solution and see how they each perform. Based on my experience, I suspect that the boolean masking operation here might be somewhat memory-inefficient.