# Reshape jagged array and fill with zeros

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

The task I wish to accomplish is the following: Consider a *1-D* array `a` and an array of indices `parts` of length `N`. Example:

```
a = np.arange(9)
parts = np.array([4, 6, 9])

# a = array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

I want to cast `a` into a *2-D* array of shape `(N, <length of longest partition in parts>)`, inserting values of `a` upto each index in `indx` in each row of the *2-D* array, filling the remaining part of the row with zeroes, like so:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 0, 0],
       [6, 7, 8, 0])
```

I do not wish to use loops. Can't wrap my head around this, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one with `boolean-indexing` -

```
def jagged_to_regular(a, parts):
    lens = np.ediff1d(parts,to_begin=parts[0])
    mask = lens[:,None]>np.arange(lens.max())
    out = np.zeros(mask.shape, dtype=a.dtype)
    out[mask] = a
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [46]: a = np.arange(9)
    ...: parts = np.array([4, 6, 9])

In [47]: jagged_to_regular(a, parts)
Out[47]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 0, 0],
       [6, 7, 8, 0]])
```