# Can this be done faster with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

There's a color **image**, a numpy array of shape `(h,w,3)` with **N**=h*w pixels; there's an array **labels** of shape `(h,w)`, each label an integer between 1 and **M**. **N** is 10^6-10^7, **M** is 10^3-10^4.

I need to produce
a **result** image (h,w,3) where the color of each pixel labelled l is the mean color of all pixels labelled l. I.e.:

```
def recolor1(image, labels):
    result = np.empty(shape=(h,w,3))
    for label in np.unique(labels):
        mask = labels==label
        mean = np.mean(image[mask], axis=0)
        result[mask] = mean
    return result
```

The code is straightforward, but runs in **O(M.N)** (the computation of `mask` is **O(N)** and the loop runs **M** times).

An O(N) `recolor2` is possible. Basically you go over the labels and image pixels twice. First to compute an auxiliary array, indexed by label, where you keep the sums of each primary and the number of pixels for that label. Then you compute the averages for each label. Then you go over labels and pixels again, computing result. The O(M) time to find the averages is noise.

With `recolor2` written in Python, `recolor1` and `recolor2` break even for N=1000000 and M=1000 at ~4s. As expected, `recolor1`'s time grows linearly to ~20s for M=5000, while `recolor2`'s remains essentially the same.

4s for a relatively small image is not great and it will get much worse for larger images. I'm no expert in numpy and associated libraries. Is there an O(N) solution there?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62836599/calculate-partitioned-sum-efficiently-with-cupy-or-numpy help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `np.bincount` and loop over the channels:

```
result = np.stack([np.bincount(labels.flat, weights=img[...,i].flat)[labels-1] 
                   for i in range(3)],
                  axis=-1)
```

which takes about 35ms on my system with `h,w,M = 1000,1000,1000`.

**Note** This compute the sum, but mean should be easy enough.

Comment: yes, this is definitely what I was looking for!

Comment: Working; 1000,750,5000 runs in 47mS!